# http.post not sending the request to local iis

Tags: angular

I am trying to post data from client to local server using local iis server. But it is not sending the request to server not showing any error.

Here is the request:

```
let url = 'http://localhost/TestApp.Web.Api/api/user';
        let body = JSON.stringify({user});
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
        this.http.post(url,body,options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
```

And here extractData method which I am using to get the data from response:

```
private extractData(res:Response){
        let body = res.json();
        console.log(body.data);
        return body.data || { };
    }
```

Any suggestion.

Comment: you have to `subscribe` to it to fire the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the result for the request to be made. Like this:

```
        this.http.post(url,body,options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError)
                    .subscribe();
```

The `http` methods return cold observables, meaning they are lazy and will not execute unless something subscribes to them.

Comment: Sorry @DerekMT12 I missed it.